# Get angle to hit (x,y) with vertex

Tags: homework-and-exercises, projectile

In a projectile trajectory, I'm using the [following equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile#Angle_required_to_hit_coordinate_.28x.2Cy.29) to get the angle required to hit a target in x,y coordinates:

[image]

This works great, however, it implies that the target is reached by one of the roots of the function.

What I want is that the target is reached with the vertex of the parabola. Is there an equation I can use?

In order to clarify what I need:

$$v_0: \rm{unkown}$$
$$\theta: \rm{unkown}$$
$$\rm{target}_x: \rm{given}$$
$$\rm{target}_y: \rm{given}$$

The equation should give me initial velocity and angle in order for the vertex of the parabola to reach the target.

[image]

Comment: Could you make a drawing of what your looking for to clarify the question?! The way I read it now you want the point of contact with the ground to be the vertex of the parabola, which is generally not possible

Comment: The point of contact with the target, which is not the ground. I will make a drawing to clarify this.

Comment: @Michiel I have updated the post with a drawing.

Comment: Note that you use $v_0$ in one place and $v$ in the other, and I think you mean for them to be the same...

Answer (score 4):

This is not a complete answer because this question looks too much like homework you are supposed to solve. What made you choose that approach? The right way to solve this problem is to solve the problem.

You want to hit some target point $(p_x,p_y)$ at the apex of the parabolic arc. Ignoring air resistance, the trajectory of an object with an initial velocity $v_0$ and an initial angle $\theta$ relative to horizontal is given by
$$\begin{aligned}
x(t) &= v\cos(\theta)\, t \\
y(t) &= v\sin(\theta)\, t - \frac 1 2 g t^2
\end{aligned}$$

The velocity at some time $t$ is given by
$$\begin{aligned}
\dot x(t) &= v\cos(\theta) \\
\dot y(t) &= v\sin(\theta) - g t
\end{aligned}$$

You want to hit the target at the top of the arc, so that means the $y$ component of velocity is zero at this point. This happens when $t = \frac v g\sin\theta$. Use this value of $t$ in the expressions for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, equate these to the target coordinates $p_x$ and $p_y$, and solve for $v_0$ and $\theta$.